# files from internal storage cannot be seen in gallery

Tags: cyanogenmod

in my samsung galaxy s2 having custom rom cyanogen 11, the files are not getting shown in gallery. i have reinstalled rom 2 times but it isn't working to show the files. i have also used the app SD scanner but then also it isn't working. please suggest me a strong way to get through this problem at once.

Comment: Run `adb shell mediaserver` for few minutes and then restart the system. Tell us the result then.

Comment: What "files" are you talking about, and where exactly do you expect them? Can you see them using a file browser?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the media isn't in a folder with this type of name > `.anyfoldername`, or hasn't any files in it with the name `.nomedia` (change the option so you can see hidden files).
If it does change the folder to `anyfoldername` or delete the file `.nomedia`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move all images in the default image folder in phone memory and also follow same procedures for the video and after that in apps clear cache the gallery....

Comment: where is default image and video folder??

Comment: And where does it say one has to do that? I've never heard of such. Any source to back your claim?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Setting-->apps--->media storage-->clear data--->OK and reboot  and check

Answer (score -1):

Setting-->apps--->all apps---->select gallery--->clear data but first create backup

Comment: i have done that too!!!  but it's not working...

Comment: Why do we do that? Also, how to backup before doing it?

Comment: No more ideas i suggest to contact Samsung customer care

Comment: Download baton app